# Modifying list in asynchronous programming

Tags: python, asynchronous

Let's say I have a class containing only one member, and it's a list.

```
class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []

    def add_to_list(self, element):
        self.l.append(element)
```

And now, I have a lot of coroutines running in parallel in `asyncio.Task`'s that executes `add_to_list` on List instance. Is this justififed to protect list by `asyncio.Lock` like this:

```
import asyncio


class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()
        self.l = []

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def add_to_list(self, element):
        with (yield from self.lock):
            self.l.append(element)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to twisted, not asyncio but I think the answer will be the same.

Asynchronous does not mean your program is multi-threaded. You're not going to have two threads reading/writing to the same variable. Async still does everything in sequence. You have to think of it as one big `while True` loop that looks whether there is something to do. When it finds something, it will execute it and go to the next. Where ever you see a yield statement. That is the point where you tell python that it is okay to do other things meanwhile that function is paused.